# How do I merge subdirectories into a single executable?

Tags: cmake

I understand that every subdirectory has to have a CMakeLists.txt, but I don't want to create a library or an executable for each directory.

My folder structure:

```
/src
  /exportedHeaders
  /server
  main.cpp
```

Each subfolder has a mix of .h and .cpp files. I don't understand how I can mix all of it up into a single executable, there doesn't seem to be a command for that.

Comment: Typically you compile the .cpp files (which include the .h files) into a single executable. Is that what you are asking about? Or do you know how to compile but are asking something else?

Comment: @jwd:  right, but how do I add cpp files inside the subfolders to the executable which gets generated from the topfolder? I think I'm missing something bigger :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't really used CMake, so there is probably a better way, but as far as I know you can just specify the path to all the source files.

eg:

```
add_executable (myProgram main.cpp subdir1/foo.cpp subdir2/bla.cpp)
```

I imagine you could use file globbing to get  `*.cpp` in each subdir, to reduce typing.
See [this mailing list message](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2006-October/011731.html) for info about file globbing in CMake.

Comment: With CMake, it is better to list your files explicitly than to use any file globbing techniques. If you list them explicitly, then you have to change your CMakeLists.txt file when you add and remove files... and the build system can note that CMakeLists.txt file is out of date and automatically re-run CMake when you make such a change. With a file globbing technique, there is no such file change occurring, and you do not get the benefit of CMake running automatically when necessary.

Comment: Yes, this is the typical way of handling this. FWIW, I typically set up my projects to have `include/`, `src/` and `test/` folders, and I usually just have one `CMakeLists.txt` file in the top directory for all my targets which may be scattered (organized!) in different source folders.

Comment: Each directory having separate cmakelists.txt